# Snowflake String extract

Tags: string, substring, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a field with multiple values in one columns separated by pipe (|) delimiter like below:

"PR|20078|ABBV|Ven|1|PS|1|DFT|efficacy|1|0|W1|Key22 CLL EASTERN|Litmus ID: 865avvwr|2022-04-28"

I want to extract "Litmus ID: 865avvwr" from the above string.

This value can show up between any of these 2 pipe delimiter in the data. Can you please help?

Thanks,
Anu

I tried using REGEXP_SUBSTR but I'm not getting the syntax right.

Comment: “I tried using REGEXP_SUBSTR but I’m not getting the syntax right.” That’s OK! :) Please [edit] your question to show us what you tried. Maybe you made a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 - use regex substr() to extract the word but if you have multiple words after `Litmus` use option 2.

```
select regexp_substr('W1|Key22 CLL EASTERN|Litmus ID: 865avvwr|2022-04-28','Litmus ID\\W+(\\w+)', 1, 1, 'e', 1)
```

Option 2 -
You can use regex instr, substring and then split part like below.

```
split_part(
  substr(mycol,
    regexp_instr(mycol,'Litmus ID')
  )
,'|',1    
) output
```

`regexp_instr()` - is used to deletermine location of the word `Litmus ID`.
`substr()` - is used to cut string from that point forward - like `Litmus ID: abcxyz|othrs`
`split_part()` - is used to split data based on | and show first part - like `Litmus ID: abcxyz`.

sample SQL -

```
select split_part(
substr('W1|Key22 CLL EASTERN|Litmus ID: 865avvwr|2022-04-28',
regexp_instr('W1|Key22 CLL EASTERN|Litmus ID: 865avvwr|2022-04-28','Litmus ID'))
,'|',1    
) c
```